# Best way to develop a barcode scanning app on android that runs until Android 4.1 (API 16) devices

Tags: android, firebase, barcode, scanning, firebase-mlkit

I'm thinking of using the Barcode Scanning API from Firebase ML Kit, then utilizing SQlite to store some information coming from my app. Is this possible and will run until Android 4.1 devices?

Answer (score 1):

From [Add Firebase to your Android project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup):

> **Prerequisites:**
>
> Install or update Android Studio to its latest version.
>
> Ensure that your Android app:
>
> Targets **API level 16 (Jelly Bean) or later** Uses Gradle 4.1 or later
>   Set up a device or emulator for running your app.
>
> Emulators must use an emulator image with Google Play. Sign into
>   Firebase using your Google account.

As I didn't understand what you mean with "*until Android 4.1*", here is a good library to use with lower level APIs: [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing)

Comment: I think ml required api level 19 or something. So he is asking whether it is possible to make app with low api level